# Алгоритм поиска пика числовой последовательности

Tags: c, алгоритм, поиск

Имеется алгоритм поиска пика последовательности, где `nel` - количетво элементов последовательности, а `*less` - указатель на функцию сравнивания двух элементов последовательности.

Язык Си:

```
unsigned long peak(unsigned long nel, int(*less)(unsigned long i, unsigned long j))
{
    if (nel < 3) return less(0, 1);
    for (unsigned long k = 1; k < (nel - 1); k++) {
        if(less(k-1, k) && less(k+1, k)) return k;
    }
}
```

Он работает для небольших по длине числовых последовательностей, но при подключения функции к программе:

```
int less(unsigned long i, unsigned long j)
{
    if (i == j) return 0;

    if (i < j) {
        if (j <= 11241155978086311589UL) return 1;
        if (i >= 11241155978086311589UL) return 0;
        return (11241155978086311589UL-i) < (j-11241155978086311589UL);
    }

    if (i <= 11241155978086311589UL) return 0;
    if (j >= 11241155978086311589UL) return 1;
    return (11241155978086311589UL-j) < (i-11241155978086311589UL);
}

unsigned long peak(unsigned long, int (*)(unsigned long, unsigned long));

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    unsigned long i = peak(13356955260197607378UL, less);
    if (i == 11241155978086311589UL) {
        printf("CORRECT\n");
    } else { 
        printf("WRONG\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Программа выполняется очень долго. Нужна идея оптимизации функции `peak()`, чтобы она работала как для коротких последовательностей, так и для данной выше программы.

Функция `peak` должна возвращать индекс любого найденного пика.

Comment: `k` - беззнаковое целое, оно всегда больше или рано нулю, в чем смысл данного условия?

Comment: @Croessmah прощу прощения, не ту версию алгоритма выкатил. Исправил.

Comment: Какая-то ерунда. Вы просто ищете какой-то неуловимый пик, сравнимая *идущие подряд* соседние числа? Т.е. вы хотите найти, где произойдет переполнение?

Comment: @Harry почему подряд? сранивают, что `k-1` и `k+1` больше или меньше `k`

Comment: Потому что вы идете по этим k подряд - `for (unsigned long k = 1; k < (nel - 1); k++)` - и хотите перебирать подряд 10^20 чисел??!! Вы поясните, что вы хотите найти, что за пик... Откуда этот пик возьмется, кроме как из переполнения (или как там оно правильно для беззнаковых называется? вечно в этой терминологии путаюсь...)?

Comment: а вообще да, ряд то убывающий, это ведь не индексы а значения. бред какой то. Пока до указанной границы нефиговой величины не дойдет, дак и не вернет ничего. не удивительно, что долго.

Comment: @Harry пик последовательности - это такое число, которое **не меньше** двух своих соседей (слева и справа соответственно)
@teran вот в том-то и дело. Допустим, для последовательности `{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 }` при другой реализации `less` значение находится элементарно и крайне быстро. А вот как под этот случай адаптировать ума не приложу.

Comment: Откуда у вас такая последовательность может взяться? У вас же **нет** последовательности. Вы просто рассматриваете подряд числа. Ну добро бы было где-то сравнение не k и k+1, а каких-то n[k] и n[k+1]... Но вы же просто сравниваете с помощью хитрой функции сравнения (кстати, вы бы ее хоть прокомментировали... почему именно такая?) идущие подряд *числа*, а не *элементы последовательности*.

Comment: @Harry скажем так, это задание. Точнее тест, который функция `peak` должна пройти за 1 секунду.

Comment: Знаете, дайте исходное задание... Уже просто интересно :)

Comment: @Harry, да, без проблем.

*Элемент последовательности чисел, значение которого – не меньше значений его непосредственных соседей, называется пиком. Очевидно, что непустая последовательность размера n имеет от 1 до n пиков.
Составьте функцию peak, возвращающую индекс любого пика в последовательности.*

Comment: А где **у вас** эта последовательность? У вас ее просто нет, вернее, вы в ее качестве берете просто последовательность 1,2,3,... Кстати, о "индекс любого пика" - видимо, хотя бы одного? или всех?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67499/discussion-between-cryptostimor-and-harry).

Comment: @cryptostimor Например чтобы решить в общем случае для всех возможных вариантов похожих на ваш пример, т.е. когда не известна точная точка но функция ведёт себя так же как в примере, т.е. вначаел возрастает до пика, а потом убывает до пика, то решается это дихотомией, т.е. делим отрезок пополам, проверяем его центр, и если в центре функция возрастает то переходим к отрезку правому, если убывает то к левому. Сходится за Log(N) шагов, т.е. очень быстро.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для решения задачи можно использовать дихотомию. Кроме того "unsigned long" насколько я знаю 32-битный, потому нужно исправить в коде на uint64_t или unsigned long long. Вот я написал решение на C (немного аккуратней код автора сделал но суть он не меняет), можно [запустить онлайн](https://repl.it/NEMq/0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef uint64_t u64;

u64 const c_peak = 11241155978086311589ULL;
u64 const c_cnt = 13356955260197607378ULL;

u64 peak(u64 nel, int(*less)(u64 i, u64 j))
{
    if (nel <= 1) return 0; // Note: if nel == 0 there is no answer!
    if (!less(0, 1)) return 0;
    if (!less(nel - 1, nel - 2)) return nel - 1;

    u64 l = 1, r = nel - 1;
    while (r - l > 2) {
        u64 m = l + (r - l) / 2;
        if (less(m + 1, m)) r = m + 1; else l = m;
    }
    if (r - l == 2 && !less(l, l + 1) || r - l <= 1) return l; else return l + 1;
}

int less(u64 i, u64 j)
{
    if (i == j) return 0;

    if (i < j) {
        if (j <= c_peak) return 1;
        if (i >= c_peak) return 0;
        return (c_peak - i) < (j - c_peak);
    } else {
        if (i <= c_peak) return 0;
        if (j >= c_peak) return 1;
        return (c_peak - j) < (i - c_peak);
    }
}

u64 peak(u64, int (*)(u64, u64));

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    u64 i = peak(c_cnt, less);
    if (i == c_peak) {
        printf("CORRECT\n");
    } else { 
        printf("WRONG\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```